# Finding long, lat coordinates of points on building pictured by drone

Tags: latitude-longitude, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

How do I get the formula for calculating lat, long coordinates on the attached picture?

Here is the EXIF file. The problem is that we don't know the horizontal distance from the building to a drone.

[image]

EXIF

```
Exif Image Size 4,864 × 3,648
Image Description   DCIM\101MEDIA\DJI_0812.JPG
Orientation Horizontal (normal)
Software    v01.07.1641
Y Cb Cr Positioning Centered
Exposure Time   1/400
F Number    5.60
Exposure Program    Program AE
ISO 100
Exif Version    0230
Date/Time Original  2019:05:12 12:55:01
    9 months, 7 days, 21 hours, 25 minutes, 11 seconds ago
Components Configuration    -, Cr, Cb, Y
Compressed Bits Per Pixel   3.132420252
Shutter Speed Value 1/400
Aperture Value  5.60
Exposure Compensation   0
Max Aperture Value  2.8
Subject Distance    0 m
Metering Mode   Center-weighted average
Light Source    Fine Weather
Flash   No flash function
Focal Length    8.8 mm
Maker Note DJI  (562 bytes binary data)
Flashpix Version    0010
Color Space sRGB
Interoperability Index  R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Interoperability Version    0100
Exposure Index  undef
File Source Digital Camera
Scene Type  Directly photographed
Custom Rendered Normal  
Exposure Mode   Auto    
White Balance   Auto    
Digital Zoom Ratio  undef   
Focal Length In 35mm Format 24 mm   
Scene Capture Type  Standard    
Gain Control    None    
Contrast    Normal  
Saturation  Normal  
Sharpness   Hard    
Subject Distance Range  Unknown 
Serial Number   4d31b8d1e1acffb45e2be9dfdbd70276    
GPS Version ID  2.3.0.0 
GPS Latitude Ref    North   
GPS Latitude    45.429768 degrees   
GPS Longitude Ref   West    
GPS Longitude   73.137033 degrees   
GPS Altitude Ref    Above Sea Level 
GPS Altitude    69.234 m    
XP Comment  Type=N, Mode=P, DE=None 
XP Keywords v01.07.1641;1.2.0;v1.0.0    
Compression JPEG (old-style)    
Thumbnail Length    10,463  
Modify Date 2019:05:12 12:55:02 
    9 months, 7 days, 21 hours, 25 minutes, 10 seconds ago
Create Date 2019:05:12 12:55:01 
    9 months, 7 days, 21 hours, 25 minutes, 11 seconds ago
Make    DJI 
Camera Model Name   FC6310  
Resolution  72 pixels/inch  
Thumbnail Image (10,463 bytes binary data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't unless you know the distance from the ground, and the pitch, roll, and yawl of the camera (in addition to the CCD size and camera lens info you have).  Plus, the onboard drone GNSS may not give you sufficient precision and accuracy to determine those coordinates without some ground control anyway.  Better would be to georeference your image to some existing data (like Google imagery) in ArcGIS or QGIS and then get the coordinates from there.

Comment: I would like mathematical solution, using angles. For that purpose I was reading the paper: https://www.preprints.org/manuscript/201906.0146/v1, and what I don't understand is the formula (11) on page 9, in particular, what is Aw. Please advice.