# Calculating point GPS location in picture

Tags: python, coordinates, gps

I have camera location (GPS coordinates) and need to calculate some points (pixels, actually it’s some detected objects points) location (GPS coordinates) that are seen from the camera. I found in the camera manual it’s viewing angle (Opposite Angle 156°, Horizontal 122°, Vertical 89°) but no other parameters that would seem to be useful. Is it possible to calculate the location of some pixels? Could you give me some hints?

I found some examples of calculating distance from the camera, but I think it’s a different problem.

Comment: Do you have many overlapping photos? Maybe you can use photogrammetry: https://geosupportsystem.se/2020/09/28/punktmoln-potree-och-laz/

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but would it help to get the GPS coordinates of some pixel in photo using code? I need to extract them automatically.

Comment: Maybe this link will help:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352095/finding-long-lat-coordinates-of-points-on-building-pictured-by-drone